# Why is ${(i^{4})}^{2n}$ = 1?

Tags: complex-numbers

I found this in my math textbook, but there's no proof as to how this conclusion was reached. I'm curious to know how.

Comment: Because $i^4=1$

Comment: Actually, you even have that $(i^4)^n = 1$. No need for the second exponent to be even !

Comment: It seems like Henning's answer has helped you. You could consider accepting his answer as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

$i^4=(i\cdot i)\cdot(i\cdot i) = (-1)\cdot(-1) = 1$, and no matter which power you raise that to, you will still get $1$.

Comment: Ah, thanks. This was pretty elementary.

Comment: It almost feels like one could define $i$ as (any) fixed fourth root of unity. Of course that requires that the complex numbers are already there before one defines $i$.

Comment: @Jeppe: Well, $1$ and $-1$ are fourth roots of unity, but are somewhat inconvenient choices for $i$. We could say that $i$ is any fixed _primitive_ fourth root of unity, but that begins to approach obfuscation ...